# How to get the code from file?

Tags: php, file, browser, edit

So, for example i have two files, index.php and test.php, i want to get the code, not the code converted to html/text, the code, of test.php and paste it to index.php and when i open index.php in the browser to see the code in the browser, again the code not the code converted to html/text. I have tried with:

```
<?php
$handle=file_get_contents("test.php", "r");
echo $handle;
//returns nothing
var_dump($handle);
//returns string(240) "
print_r($handle);
//returns nothing
```

Comment: Try `requiere` or `include` ...cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code is invisible, because it is inside <?php ?> tag and browser doesn't know how to render it.

Your options are:

a)
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
echo $handle;

b)
echo htmlspecialchars($handle);

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP starts with `<?..?>`, the browser will typically try to interpret that as HTML tags, which will make the contents disappear and/or display in a rather screwed up way. You need to encode such special characters to HTML entities to have them display correctly in an HTML context:

```
echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('test.php'));
```

Answer (score 0):

use htmlentities to output the code:

```
echo htmlentities($handle);
```